# I want to Install SIMBA ODBC drivers in AZURE PAAS

Tags: azure, odbc, azure-databricks, paas, simba

I have implemented a .Net console application which pulls the data from databricks Applications .
I have installed SIMBA ODBC drivers in my local and was able to connect to databricks cluster from my local .net application.

Now I want to host my .net application in  AZURE PAAS .So how do I install SIMBA ODBC drivers in AZURE PAAS ?

Please let me know . Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

As that resembles you are connecting to Hive using .Net Application.

You can use data bricks REST API.
https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/index.html

(OR)

You can use the docker Image Container by adding Docker to your application and run the docker file. so that the dependency drivers & Application gets installed & form an image container. The Image needs to be registered in the Azure container instance & link the container instance to Azure App Service.

Comment: Thank you so much Sai Teja. Appreciate if you share any URL

Comment: Do we need to download docker desktop for this?